# How to retrieve NSCollectionViewItems from a NSCollectionView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I just implemented an NSCollectionView just like the one described on the [developer page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CollectionViews/Introduction/Introduction.html) and it work perfectly.

Now, how can I access to collectionViewItems from CollectionView?

Comment: Why do you need the actual `NSCollectionViewItems`?  Shouldn't their represented objects have all the info you need?

Comment: Imagine for example a single selection behaviour: when I select an item, the item send an event to collectionView, and collectionView tell to others items to change its status.

Comment: the collection item could detect when it was clicked and post a notification for the other collection items to respond to appropriately.

Comment: My collectionView will act as an observer/controller for his items. So, it will decide whenever to send messages to items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you *really* need to enumerate all items in a collection view, then:

```
NSUInteger numberOfItems = [[collectionView content] count];
for (NSUInteger itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < numberOfItems; itemIndex++) {
    NSCollectionViewItem *item = [collectionView itemAtIndex:itemIndex];
    // do something with item
}
```

should do the trick on Mac OS X v10.6+.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.0

```
let allSections = self.collectionView.numberOfSections
      (0..<allSections).forEach { aSection in
        let items = self.collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: aSection)
        (0..<items).forEach { item in
            let indexpath = IndexPath(item: item, section: aSection)
            if let item = self.collectionView.item(at: indexpath) {
                print(item)
            }
        }
    }
```